# how to convert a json response to a text output.?

Tags: php, json, ideamart

I am using a platforme call ideamart to create some sms based applications.
They provide a api called subscription api.

[deatils about ideamart subscription API](http://www.ideamart.lk/web/idea-pro/documentation/idea-pro/subscription-api/)

[Guid to work with subscription API](https://nuwanjaliyagoda.blogspot.com/2016/01/how-to-use-subscription-api-on-ideamart.html)

I use below first code to request BaseSize details.is that code is correct.?
can I Display response using PHP echo() Function .? or any other way.?

```
  <?php 
 include_once "definitions.php";
 include_once "subscription.php";
 $sub = new Subscription();
 $AppId = "APP_00001";
 $Password = "yuhst345";
 $baseSize = $sub->getBaseSize($AppId,$Password);
 ?>
```

here is the getBaseSize function that includes in subscription.php

```
public function getBaseSize($applicationId, $password){
    $arrayField = array(
        "applicationId" => $applicationId,
        "password" => $password);

    $jsonObjectFields = json_encode($arrayField);
    $resp=$this->sendBaseRequest($jsonObjectFields);
    $response = json_decode($resp, true);

    $statusDetail = $response['statusDetail'];
    $statusCode = $response['statusCode'];
    $status =$response['baseSize'];

    return $status;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it looks like your `getBaseSize()` is returning an simply the base size.  So, you should be able to do a

`print $baseSize;`
OR
`echo $baseSize;`

And you'll print out the string.